# Library to automatically organize taxonomy

Tags: python, taxonomy

I've got the following taxonomy for a list of items:

Example:

```
Item 1['taxonomy'] = 'toys/starwars/yoda/Baby Yoda toy'
Item 2['taxonomy'] = 'toys/starwars/yoda/Baby Yoda toy 10inches'
Item 3['taxonomy'] = 'toys/starwars/luke/Luke Skywalker toy'
Item 4['taxonomy'] = 'cloths/starwars/luke/Luke Skywalker toy'
```

And I want to automatically create one taxonomy "object" with a representation like

```
|_ toys (3)
|     |_
|       starwars (3)
|              |_ yoda
|              |_ luke
|                 ...
|_ cloths (1)
               ...
```

Do I have to do it manually or is there any library/object that does it?
Thanks

I don't necessarily want a tree! I want to organize my taxonomy and understand the taxonomy behavior (understand how well it is structured for all the articles)

How can I also print the tree without the last branch?

Comment: What data structure should the response look like? What operations do you want to perform on the result?

Comment: I want to organize my taxonomy and understand the taxonomy behavior (understand how well it is structured for all the articles)

Comment: *Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more* renders a question off topic here.

Comment: maybe you could rephfrase your question as "creating a taxonomy tree from a list of paths" or something alike

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to create a tree.
You could represent your data with [anytree](https://anytree.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

```
from anytree import Node, RenderTree

def parse_taxonomy_path(tx, nodes):
    l = s.split('/')

    parent = l[0]
    nodes[parent] = Node(parent, parent=nodes['root'])
    
    for i in range(1,len(l)):
        name = l[i]
        nodes[name] = Node(name, parent=nodes[parent])
        parent = name
    
    return nodes
    
root = Node('root')
nodes = {'root':root}

nodes = parse_taxonomy_path('toys/starwars/yoda/Baby Yoda toy', nodes)

for pre, _, node in RenderTree(root):
    print("%s%s" % (pre, node.name))
```

```
root
└── toys
    └── starwars
        └── yoda
            └── Baby Yoda toy
```

Comment: Now, that is a real answer worth an upvote ;-) (albeit the question is still off topic)

Comment: That code doesn't do what's in the example !

Answer (score 0):

```py
from anytree import Node, RenderTree

def parse_taxonomy_path(tx, nodes):
    l = tx.split('/')

    parent = l[0]
    nodes[parent] = Node(parent, parent=nodes['root'])
    
    for i in range(1,len(l)):
        name = l[i]
        nodes[name] = Node(name, parent=nodes[parent])
        parent = name
    
    return nodes
    
root = Node('root')
nodes = {'root':root}

nodes = parse_taxonomy_path('toys/starwars/yoda/Baby Yoda toy', nodes)

for pre, _, node in RenderTree(root):
    print("%s%s" % (pre, node.name))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details about your code.

Answer (score 0):

Using a tree seems like the simplest solution.
For this I recommend using [littletree](https://pypi.org/project/littletree/) of which I'm the author. Although it's relatively new (even newer than the question)

```py
from littletree.exporters.stringexporter import Style
from littletree.serializers import RowSerializer

# Load tree into memory
items = [
    'toys/starwars/yoda/Baby Yoda toy',
    'toys/starwars/yoda/Baby Yoda toy 10inches',
    'toys/starwars/luke/Luke Skywalker toy',
    'cloths/starwars/luke/Luke Skywalker toy',
]


serializer = RowSerializer(path_name=None)
tree = serializer.from_rows([item.split('/') for item in items])


def display_descendants(node):
    """Not sure what the number between parentheses means. I assume number of descendants."""
    num_descendants = sum(1 for _ in node.iter_descendants())
    return f"{node.identifier} ({num_descendants})"


def skip_last_branch(node, _):
    """
    Not sure what you mean by "Skip the last branch". I interpret is as excluding leaves.
    This function takes 2 parameters
    - First is node
    - Second is a tuple of (index, depth).
    """
    return not node.is_leaf

# String representation
print(tree.to_string(str_factory=display_descendants,
                     keep=skip_last_branch,
                     style=Style(branch="|_", last="|_", vertical="| ")))

# Image representation
tree.to_image('sw.png',
              keep=skip_last_branch,
              node_attributes={"label": display_descendants})
```

The output looks like this:

```
node (11)
|_ toys (6)
|  |_ starwars (5)
|     |_ yoda (2)
|     |_ luke (1)
|_ cloths (3)
   |_ starwars (2)
      |_ luke (1)
```

You can probably customize this further.

[Here is an image of your taxonomy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJFVY.png)

Answer (score 0):

A tree structure would be good for this usage. There are 2 main steps - first to create the tree and next to print the tree in the taxonomy that you want.

It can be done using `bigtree` as such,

```py
# Your data - I added "root" as a prefix so every path belongs to the same tree
path_list = [
    "root/toys/starwars/yoda/Baby Yoda toy",
    "root/toys/starwars/yoda/Baby Yoda toy 10inches",
    "root/toys/starwars/luke/Luke Skywalker toy",
    "root/cloths/starwars/luke/Luke Skywalker toy",
]

from bigtree import list_to_tree, yield_tree

# Construct tree
root = list_to_tree(path_list)

# Print tree
for pre_str, fill_str, _node in yield_tree(root):
    if _node.is_leaf:
        print(f"{pre_str}{fill_str}{_node.name}")
    else:
        print(f"{pre_str}{fill_str}{_node.name} ({len(list(_node.descendants))})")
```

This will result in the output:

```
root (11)
├── toys (6)
│   └── starwars (5)
│       ├── yoda (2)
│       │   ├── Baby Yoda toy
│       │   └── Baby Yoda toy 10inches
│       └── luke (1)
│           └── Luke Skywalker toy
└── cloths (3)
    └── starwars (2)
        └── luke (1)
            └── Luke Skywalker toy
```

Disclaimer: I'm the author of `bigtree` ;)